# GetFileByServerRelativeUrl - moveto : Getting (400)Bad Request Error

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using SharePoint 2013 REST API and getting (400)Bad Request error when moving file from one Document Library to different Site-Sub Site's document library.

My hierarchy look like this -

Source - Project->**SiteA**->SubSite->DocLib->File.txt

Destination - Project->**SiteB**->SubSite->DocLib->File.txt

I am getting **success** when DocLib is in same subsite. Please suggest where I am getting wrong.

`http://siteurl/SiteA/SubSite/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@source)/moveto(newurl=@destination,flags=1)?@source='siteurl/SiteA/SubSite/Client/AAAAA/File.txt'&@destination='siteurl/SiteB/SubSite/Client/AAAAA/File.txt'`

Comment: Make sure you use server-relative url for both source and destination. So for http://server/SiteA/SubSite/Client/AAA/File.txt that is /SiteA/SubSite/Client/AAA/File.txt

Comment: yeah, the urls are correct as I am getting success when the two libraries are on same SubSite, the problem is when SubSite in different Site i.e SiteB->SubSite

Comment: Are you providing a valid request digest? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints#writing-data-by-using-the-rest-interface

Comment: I am passing the digest of SiteA->SubSite's page. [request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", formDigest);] This is digest of Source's

Comment: @StevenVandeCraen, Is that due to digest? If yes then how to resolve? any suggesstions?

Comment: looking into a working sample. cross site copying might be a limitation of the REST API.

Comment: Seems like a limitation indeed. I've looked at my code and it uses the Copy SOAP service (/_vti_bin/copy.asmx) CopyIntoItemsLocal method. Other parts of the code use REST, so I probably ran into the same issue.