# REST API to move a folder with it's content

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, move, copy

Is there any endpoint in Sharepoint 2016 REST API to move the folder and it's content to another location? Even if we have a copy folder and it's content it's fine. Please let us know.

**Note:** we are using Sharepoint 2016 and not Office 365.

Comment: I Just found the GetFolderByServerRelativeURL.moveTo [link](_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{0}')/moveTo(newurl='{1}') and it is working. is there anything i am missing?

Comment: Look at this too it's for files: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/244071/getfilebyserverrelativeurl-moveto-getting-400bad-request-error

Comment: I have requirement to move file from one folder to another sub folder under same library in sharepoint using REST API.I am new to this. Can you provide details or Postman json file